# Configuring ALB with IBM HTTP Server

Tags: http, aws-application-load-balancer, loadbalancer

I am completely new to the concept of Load balancer. Currently, I have a HTTP server and two application servers integrated which works as an application. I am trying to integrate load balancer into the existing setup.

Created one load balancer, if user hits Load balancer URL(https://example.com), it will automatically point to HTTP server as target group.

Just curious to know, if I can replace HTTP server hostURL with ALB URL inside application, will it work. Suppose previously application can be reached through (http://exam.com/welcome.jsp), if I change as https://example.com/welcome.jsp inside application. Any additional configuration needs to be added.

Thanks in advance!!

Trying to get background knowledge on it.